# Is pointers within structures slowing down my code?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, structure

I am looking for some help or hints to speed up my code.

I have implemented a routine for computing the gravitational potential at a point (r,phi,lambda) in space from a set of spherical harmonic coefficients C_{n,m} and S_{n,m}. The equation is shown in the link below:

[image: Equation that is being implemented]

and includes the recursive computation of the latitude (phi) dependent associated Legendre polynomials P_{n,m}, starting with the first two values P{0,0} and P_{1,1}.

At first, I had this implemented as a MATLAB C-MEX code, with only the core part of my code in C-language. I wanted to make a pure C-routine, but found that the code runs 3-5 times slower, which makes me wonder why. Could it be the way I define my structures and use pointers to pointers in the central code?
It seems like it is the core computation part that takes the extra time, but that part did not change although before I was passing using pointers directly to variables and now I am using pointers inside structures.
Any help is appreciated!

In the following, I will try to explain my code and show some extracts:

At the beginning of the program, I define three structures. One to hold the spherical harmonic coefficients, C_{n,m} and S_{n,m}, (ggm_struct), one to hold the computation coordinates (comp_struct) and one to hold the results (func_struct):

```
// Define constant variables
const double deg2rad = M_PI/180.0;                 // degrees to radians conversion factor
const double sfac = 1.0000E-280;                   // scaling factor
const double sqrt2 = 1.414213562373095;            // sqrt(2)
const double sqrt3 = 1.732050807568877;            // sqrt(3)

// Define structure to hold geopotential model
struct ggm_struct {
    char   product_type[100], modelname[100], errors[100], norm[100], tide_system[100];
    double GM, R, *C, *S;
    int    max_degree, ncoef;
};
// Define structure to hold computation coordinates
struct comp_struct {
    double *lat, *lon, *h;
    double *r, *phi;
    int    nlat, nlon;
};
/* Define structure to hold results */
struct func_struct {
    double *rval;
    int    npoints;
};
```

I then have a (sub-)function that starts by allocating space and then loads the coefficients from an ascii file as

```
int read_gfc(char mfile[100], int *nmax, int *mmax, struct ggm_struct *ggm)
{

    // Set file identifier
    FILE *fid;

    // Declare variables
    char   str[200], var[100];
    int    n, m, nid, l00 = 0, l10 = 0, l11 = 0;
    double c, s;

    // Determine number of coefficients
    ggm->ncoef = (*nmax+2)*(*nmax+1)/2;

    // Allocate memory for coefficients
    ggm->C = (double*) malloc(ggm->ncoef*sizeof(double));
    if (ggm->C == NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for C not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    ggm->S = (double*) malloc(ggm->ncoef*sizeof(double));
    if (ggm->S == NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for S not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    // Open file
    fid = fopen(mfile,"r");

    // Check that file was opened correctly
    if (fid == NULL){
        printf("Error: opening file %s!",mfile);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    // Read file header
    while (fgets(str,200,fid) != NULL && strncmp(str,"end_of_head",11) != 0){

        // Extract model parameters
        if (strncmp(str,"product_type",12) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %s",var,ggm->product_type); }
        if (strncmp(str,"modelname",9) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %s",var,ggm->modelname); }
        if (strncmp(str,"earth_gravity_constant",22) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %lf",var,&ggm->GM); }
        if (strncmp(str,"radius",6) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %lf",var,&ggm->R); }
        if (strncmp(str,"max_degree",10) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %d",var,&ggm->max_degree); }
        if (strncmp(str,"errors",6) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %s",var,ggm->errors); }
        if (strncmp(str,"norm",4) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %s",var,ggm->norm); }
        if (strncmp(str,"tide_system",11) == 0){ sscanf(str,"%s %s",var,ggm->tide_system); }

    }

    // Read coefficients
    while (fgets(str,200,fid) != NULL){

        // Extract parameters
        sscanf(str,"%s %d %d %lf %lf",var,&n,&m,&c,&s);

        // Store parameters
        if (n <= *nmax && m <= *mmax) {

            // Determine index
            nid = (n+1)*n/2 + m;

            // Store values
            *(ggm->C+nid) = c;
            *(ggm->S+nid) = s;

        }

    }

    // Close fil
    fclose(fid);

    // Return from function
    return 0;

}
```

Afterwards, the computation grid is defined by an array of seven components. As an example, the array [-90 90 -180 180 1 1 0] defines a grid from -90 to 90 degrees latitude at 1-degree increments and from -180 to 180 degrees longitude at 1-degree increments. The height is zero. From this array, a computation grid is generated in a (sub-)function:

```
int make_grid(double *grid, struct comp_struct *inp)
{

    // Declare variables
    int n;

    /* Echo routine */
    printf("Creating grid of coordinates\n");
    printf("             [lat1,lat2,dlat] = [%f,%f,%f]\n", *grid, *(grid+1), *(grid+4) );
    printf("             [lon1,lon2,dlon] = [%f,%f,%f]\n", *(grid+2), *(grid+3), *(grid+5) );
    printf("             h                = %f\n", *(grid+6));

    /* Latitude ------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // Determine number of increments
    inp->nlat = ceil( ( *(grid+1) - *grid + *(grid+4) ) / *(grid+4) );

    // Allocate memory
    inp->lat = (double*) malloc(inp->nlat*sizeof(double));
    if (inp->lat== NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for LATITUDE (inp.lat) points not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    // Fill in values
    *(inp->lat) = *(grid+1);
    for (n = 1; n < inp->nlat-1; n++) {
        *(inp->lat+n) = *(inp->lat+n-1) - *(grid+4);
    }
    *(inp->lat+inp->nlat-1) = *grid;

    /* Longitude ------------------------------------------------------------ */

    // Determine number of increments
    inp->nlon = ceil( ( *(grid+3) - *(grid+2) + *(grid+5) ) / *(grid+5) );

    // Allocate memory
    inp->lon = (double*) malloc(inp->nlon*sizeof(double));
    if (inp->lon== NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for LONGITUDE (inp.lon) points not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    // Fill in values
    *(inp->lon) = *(grid+2);
    for (n = 1; n < inp->nlon-1; n++) {
        *(inp->lon+n) = *(inp->lon+n-1) + *(grid+5);
    }
    *(inp->lon+inp->nlon-1) = *(grid+3);

    /* Height --------------------------------------------------------------- */

    // Allocate memory
    inp->h = (double*) malloc(inp->nlat*sizeof(double));
    if (inp->h== NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for HEIGHT (inp.h) points not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    // Fill in values
    for (n = 0; n < inp->nlat; n++) {
        *(inp->h+n) = *(inp->h+n-1) + *(grid+6);
    }

    // Return from function
    return 0;

}
```

These geographic coordinates are then transformed to spherical coordinates for the computation using another (sub-)routine

```
int geo2sph(struct comp_struct *inp, int *lgrid)
{

    // Declare variables
    double a = 6378137.0, e2 = 6.69437999014E-3; /* WGS84 parameters */
    double x, y, z, sinlat, coslat, sinlon, coslon, R_E;
    int    i, j, nid;

    /* Allocate space ------------------------------------------------------- */
    
    // radius
    inp->r = (double*) malloc(inp->nlat*sizeof(double));
    if (inp->r== NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for SPHERICAL DISTANCE (inp.r) points not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    // phi
    inp->phi = (double*) malloc(inp->nlat*sizeof(double));
    if (inp->phi== NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for SPHERICAL LATITUDE (inp.phi) points not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    /* Loop over latitude =================================================== */
    for (i = 0; i < inp->nlat; i++) {

        // Compute sine and cosine of latitude
        sinlat = sin(*(inp->lat+i));
        coslat = cos(*(inp->lat+i));

        // Compute radius of curvature
        R_E = a / sqrt( 1.0 - e2*sinlat*sinlat );

        // Compute sine and cosine of longitude
        sinlon = sin(*(inp->lon));
        coslon = cos(*(inp->lon));

        // Compute rectangular coordinates
        x = ( R_E + *(inp->h+i) ) * coslat * coslon;
        y = ( R_E + *(inp->h+i) ) * coslat * sinlon;
        z = ( R_E*(1.0-e2) + *(inp->h+i) ) * sinlat;

        // Compute sqrt( x^2 + y^2 )
        R_E = sqrt( x*x + y*y );

        // Derive radial distance
        *(inp->r+i) = sqrt( R_E * R_E + z*z );

        // Derive spherical latitude
        if (R_E < 1) {
            if (z > 0) { *(inp->phi+i) = M_PI/2.0; }
            else { *(inp->phi+i) = -M_PI/2.0; }
        }
        else {
            *(inp->phi+i) = asin( z / *(inp->r+i) );
        }

    }

    // Return from function
    return 0;

}
```

Finally, the gravitational potential is computed within is own (sub-)function. This is the core part of the code, which is more or less the same as for the MATLAB C-MEX function. The only difference seems to be that before (in MATLAB MEX) everything was defined as (simple) double variables - now the variables are located inside a structure which contains pointers.

```
int gravpot(struct comp_struct *inp, struct ggm_struct *ggm, int *nmax,
    int *mmax, int *lgrid, struct func_struct *out)
{

    // Declare variables
    double GMr, ar, t, u, u2, arn, gnm, hnm, P, Pp1, Pp2, msum;
    double Pmm[*nmax+1], CPnm[*mmax+1], SPnm[*mmax+1];
    int i, j, n, m, id;

    // Allocate memory
    out->rval = (double*) malloc(inp->nlat*inp->nlon*sizeof(double));
    if (out->rval== NULL){
        printf("Error: Memory for OUTPUT (out.rval) not allocated!");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    /* Compute sectorial values of associated Legendre polynomials ========== */

    // Define seed values ( divided by u^m )
    Pmm[0] = sfac;
    Pmm[1] = sqrt3 * sfac;

    // Compute sectorial values, [1] eq. 13 and 28 ( divided by u^m )
    for (m = 2; m <= *nmax; m++) {
        Pmm[m] = sqrt( (2.0*m+1.0) / (2.0*m) ) * Pmm[m-1];
    }

    /* ====================================================================== */

    /* Loop over latitude =================================================== */
    for (i = 0; i < inp->nlat; i++) {
      
        // Compute ratios to be used in summation
        GMr = ggm->GM / *(inp->r+i);
        ar  = ggm->R / *(inp->r+i);

        /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
         * Compute product of Legendre values and spherical harmonic coefficients.
         * Products of similar degree are summed together, resulting in mmax
         * values. The degree terms are latitude dependent, such that these mmax
         * sums are valid for every point with the same latitude.
         * The values of the associated Legendre polynomials, Pnm, are scaled by
         * sfac = 10^(-280) and divided by u^m in order to prevent underflow and
         * overflow of the coefficients.
         * ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

        // Form coefficients for Legendre recursive algorithm
        t   = sin(*(inp->phi+i));
        u   = cos(*(inp->phi+i));
        u2  = u * u;
        arn = ar;

        /* Degree n = 0 terms ----------------------------------------------- */

        // Compute order m = 0 term (S term is zero)
        CPnm[0] = Pmm[0] * *(ggm->C);

        /* Degree n = 1 terms ----------------------------------------------- */

        // Compute (1,1) terms, [1] eq. 3
        CPnm[1] = ar * Pmm[1] * *(ggm->C+2);
        SPnm[1] = ar * Pmm[1] * *(ggm->S+2);

        // Compute (1,0) Legendre value, [1] eq. 18 and 27
        P = t * Pmm[1];

        // Add (1,0) terms to sum (S term is zero), [1] eq. 3
        CPnm[0] = CPnm[0] + ar * P * *(ggm->C+1);

        /* Degree n = [2,n_max] --------------------------------------------- */
        for (n = 2; n <= *nmax; n++) {

            // Compute power term
            arn = arn * ar;

            /* Compute sectorial (m=n) terms ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */
        
            // Extract associated Legendre value
            Pp1 = Pmm[n];

            // Compute product terms, [1] eq. 3
            if (n <= *mmax) {
                id = (n+1)*n/2 + n;
                CPnm[n] = arn * Pp1 * *(ggm->C+id);
                SPnm[n] = arn * Pp1 * *(ggm->S+id);
            }

            /* Compute first non-sectorial terms (m=n-1) ++++++++++++++++++++ */

            // Compute associated Legendre value, [1] eq. 18 and 27
            gnm = sqrt( 2.0*n );
            P   = gnm * t * Pp1;
        
            // Add terms to summation, eq. 3 in [1]
            if (n-1 <= *mmax) {
                id = (n+1)*n/2 + n - 1;
                CPnm[n-1] = CPnm[n-1] + arn * P * *(ggm->C+id);
                SPnm[n-1] = SPnm[n-1] + arn * P * *(ggm->S+id);
            }

            /* Compute terms of order m = [n-2,1] +++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */
            for (m = n-2; m > 0; m--) {

                // Set previous values
                Pp2 = Pp1;
                Pp1 = P;
        
                // Compute associated Legendre value, [1] eq. 18, 19 and 27
                gnm = 2.0*(m+1.0) / sqrt( (n-m)*(n+m+1.0) );
                hnm = sqrt( (n+m+2.0)*(n-m-1.0)/(n-m)/(n+m+1.0) );
                P   = gnm * t * Pp1 - hnm * u2 * Pp2;

                // Add product terms to summation, eq. 3 in [1]
                if (m <= *mmax) {
                    id = (n+1)*n/2 + m;
                    CPnm[m] = CPnm[m] + arn * P * *(ggm->C+id);
                    SPnm[m] = SPnm[m] + arn * P * *(ggm->S+id);
                }

            }

            /* Compute zonal terms (m=0) ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */

            // Compute associated Legendre value, [1] eq. 18, 19 and 27
            gnm = 2.0 / sqrt( n*(n+1.0) );
            hnm = sqrt( (n+2.0)*(n-1.0)/n/(n+1.0) );
            P   = ( gnm * t * P - hnm * u2 * Pp1 ) / sqrt2;

            // Add terms to summation (S term is zero), [1] eq. 3
            id = (n+1)*n/2;
            CPnm[0] = CPnm[0] + arn * P * *(ggm->C+id);

        } /* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

        /* Loop over longitude ============================================== */
        for (j = 0; j < inp->nlon; j++) {
        
            /* -----------------------------------------------------------------
             * All associated Legendre polynomials (latitude dependent) are now
             * computed and multiplied by the corresponding spherical harmonic
             * coefficient. These products are scaled by u^m, meaning that
             * Horner's scheme is used in the following summation.
             * -------------------------------------------------------------- */
      
            // Initialise order-dependent sum
            msum = 0.0;

            // Derive longitude id
            id = j + i * *lgrid;
            
            // Loop over order (m > 0)
            for (m = *mmax; m > 0; m--) {

                // Add to order-dependent sum using Horner's scheme, [1] eq. 2, 3 and 31
                msum = ( msum + cos( m * *(inp->lon+id) ) * CPnm[m] 
                    + sin( m * *(inp->lon+id) ) * SPnm[m] ) * u;
      
            }

            // Add zero order term to sum
            msum = msum + CPnm[0];

            // Rescale value into gravitational potential, [1] eq. 1
            *(out->rval+i+j*inp->nlat) = GMr * msum / sfac;
    
        } /* ================================================================ */

    } /* ==================================================================== */

    // Return from function
    return 0;

}
```

Again, any help is greatly appreciated and additional information can be supplied if relevant, but this already became a long post. I have a hard time accepting that pure c-code runs slower than the MATLAB C-MEX code.

Comment: Profiling is the best way to figure out the performance issues. That said... There is a lot of malloc here. Is that part of the new approach? Malloc is slow...

Comment: "It seems like it is the core computation part that takes the extra time" - Did you do any benchmarking/profiling on this ? If so , please share the results so we can help you further.

Comment: you use "sin" and "cos" function. Depending on how much precision you want, it may be faster to have an array with all the value calculed before (just to be clear, you literaly wrote the result, you don't call the function).

Comment: With the types of calculations you have I doubt that a few extra pointer directions can cause major changes but just to repeat: Profiler...

Comment: I don't see any times in your post. What is the time if you get rid of all your C and just use Matlab's optimized matrix code compared to yours?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have never tried profiling, but will look into it - do you recommend any specific profiling tool?

Comment: What is typical values for `*nmax` and `*mmax`

Comment: oh... just to make sure: You have turned compiler optimization on! ?

Comment: You have a lot of code like `*(ggm->C+id);` that is repeated several times. Instead you can do: `double* tmpC = ggm->C;` in the start and inside the loops just do `tmpC[id]` so that your code only do one indirection instead of two. You can try it (several places) but I'm not sure it will give you much

Comment: The code of `make_grid` is not valid: the line `*(inp->h+n-1)` with `n=0` causes a read in memory at an unsafe location possibly resulting in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Typical values are nmax = 2190 and mmax = 2160.
I am not sure what compiler optimization is? And how to turn it on/off.
Thanks for the hints!

Comment: If you are using gcc or clang, enable optimisations with either -O2 or -O3. Also worth setting the architecture flags as well, e.g. -march=skylake.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply, yes, pointers can prevent some compiler optimizations resulting in a potential slow down. At least, this is clearly the case with ICC and a bit with GCC. The performance of the program is strongly impacted by **pointer aliasing and vectorization**.

Indeed, the compiler cannot easily know if the provided pointers alias each other or alias with the address with some fields of the provided data structure. As a result, the compilers tends to be *conservative* and assume that the pointed value can change at any time and *reload them often*. This can prevent optimizations like the splitting of some loops in `gravpot` (with GCC -- see line 119 of [this modified code](https://godbolt.org/z/rzWr3nhzW)). Moreover, indirections and aliasing tends to prevent the vectorization of the hot loops (ie. the use of SIMD instructions provided by the target processor). Vectorisation can strongly impact the performance of a code.

To give an example, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MohnqoP6x) is the initial code of `geo2sph` and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v5G5P5cWE) is a slightly modified implementation. In the first case, ICC generate a slow scalar implementation, while in the second case, ICC generate a significantly faster vectorized implementation. The only difference between the two implementation is the use of the **`restrict`** keyword. This keyword tell to the compiler that for the lifetime of the pointer, only the pointer itself or a value directly derived from it (such as pointer+1) will be used to access the object to which it points (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) for more information). Note that the use of the *`restrict` keyword is dangerous* and one should be *very careful* while using it since the compiler may generate a bad code if the restrict hint is wrong (very hard to debug). Alternatively, you can help the compiler to generate a vectorized code using the **OpenMP SIMD directive `#pragma omp simd`** (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/41j6nE6T1) for the result). Note that you should be sure the target code can be safely vectorized (eg. iterations of must be independent).

Comment: Thank you Jérôme for this very insightful answer. I very much appreciate it!

Comment: I have now tried implementing the modifications as you suggested: (1) creating local constant copies of the input variables; (2) using the restrict keyword; (3) using the #pragma omp simd statement. None of these modification lead to any significant change in run-time. However, using the optimization statement -O2 during compiling made everything run about twice as fast.

Comment: Sadly the modifications may or may not be useful regarding the compiler used. For example, GCC tends to not care about the use of `restrict` in data structure while ICC use this *hint*. Making copies help a bit GCC, but not sufficiently (it sometimes apply bad optimizations that can reduce performance in some case and the only way to fix that is to use compiler hacks so far). GCC tends to ignore the `#pragma omp simd` too while ICC and Clang take that into account. The problem is that most operations to fix that are hint that only works if the compiler consider. What compiler do you use?

Comment: I use the GCC compiler. Since the number of computation points may be very large, I am also not sure making local copies is the way to go.